# postgresql 11.5 - could not resize shared memory segment "/PostgreSQL.xxx" to yyy bytes: Interrupted system call

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I recently upgraded postgres 9.6 to 11.5 on AWS RDS.

And From time to time, I got this error message

`could not resize shared memory segment "/PostgreSQL.1348134852" to 2097152 bytes: Interrupted system call`

I saw some questions on 'could not resize shared memory segment' but those problme were caused by ': No space left on device' which is different with this question I think.

Do you have any idea of the root reason or how to handle it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running out of shared memory for communication between parallel worker processes.

Given that you were happy with the processing in 9.6, which has only vestigial parallel processing, I would say that the best solution would be to set `max_parallel_workers_per_gather` to 0, which will disable parallel query.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! Then there would be two possible solution, first is what you said, second is to increasing shared memory. I'll adopt your solution. Thanks!

But may I ask again the reason of 'Interrupted system call'? Why the message say the query is interrupted?

Comment: Hm, actually I don't know. You may not be OOM after all. But disabling parallel query will prevent the system call, so it cannot be interrupted any more...

Comment: oh, You are right. Thanks for your easy-to-apply answer!! :)