# ERROR: could not resize shared memory segment "/PostgreSQL.1234022056" to 134217728 bytes: No space left on device SQL state: 53100

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

For this problem, I have already looked at the following solutions:

1. [Postgres cant vacuum despite enough space left (could not resize shared memory segment bytes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65408407/postgres-cant-vacuum-despite-enough-space-left-could-not-resize-shared-memory-s)
2. [docker SHM_SIZE /dev/shm: resizing shared memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56839975/docker-shm-size-dev-shm-resizing-shared-memory)
3. [postgresql 11.5 - could not resize shared memory segment "/PostgreSQL.xxx" to yyy bytes: Interrupted system call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64094389/postgresql-11-5-could-not-resize-shared-memory-segment-postgresql-xxx-to-yy)
4. [pq: could not resize shared memory segment. No space left on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56751565/pq-could-not-resize-shared-memory-segment-no-space-left-on-device)
5. [docker SHM_SIZE /dev/shm: resizing shared memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56839975/docker-shm-size-dev-shm-resizing-shared-memory)

Earlier, I was getting this error for 1-2 queries, now I'm getting this error for multiple queries that was executed earlier in milliseconds.

A few days ago Postgres container was using *1400% CPU *and whenever I'm running those queries that are throwing no space left on this device, CPU usage around is between 500-800%.

I have checked everything the **hard disk space, RAM etc.. shared buffer increases to 6GB** but didn't worked in any cases.

I'm not setting max_parallel_workers_per_gather to 0 because many users are currently using the interface and it might affect the parallel execution.

*Shared buffer, work memory and maintenance work memory* I have tried to tweak it.

What might be the issue here?

I tried to increasing/decreasing shared buffer memory maintenance work memory and work memory.

Also, checked the indexes size and it's good a total of 18 GB indexes we're using in 55GB size of a database.

Didn't ran the vacuum because dead tuples are very less as I have checked through the command.

Server RAM is 30GB and most of the time around 23GB showing available, Disk space is 1TB and usage showing is 26%.

Currently, we're running the Docker using below configuration.

Postgres version is 11

```
postgres:
    container_name: production_slate_postgres
    # we use the postgres base image, version 5.6.36
    image: postgres:11
    restart: always
    shm_size: '1gb'
    ports:
      - "4001:5432"
    # we mount a datavolume to make sure we don't loose data
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./postgresql.conf:/var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf
    # setting some envvars to create the DB
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=${POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD}
      - POSTGRESQL_SHARED_PRELOAD_LIBRARIES=pgaudit, pg_stat_statements
```

Ran this `df -h | grep shm` command and shm memory is showing 64MB outside the container and usage is 0%.

But I enter into the Postgres container and watch the logs and got to know it's touching the SHM size

```
root@e8d1b4a4fb7e:/# df -h | grep shm
shm             1.0G  407M  618M  40% /dev/shm
```

The second column goes to 1002 MB and around 800-900 MB while I'm running the queries for which getting the space error.

So, I wanted a solution that will be helpful in long term as well.

If I will increase the shm size to 2GB to 3GB it might be a temporary solution for now.

Comment: Surely you need shared_buffers set to a value SMALLER than the shared-memory limit you have defined in docker?

Comment: @RichardHuxton Okay, currently I checked shared buffer memory set to 6GB and maintenance_work_mem is 3GB and work_mem is 64MB. And as I have mentioned shm_size is 1GB.

Should I give a try to lower the value of shared buffer and any other?

Comment: @RichardHuxton - Little confused with your response as you have put a question mark at the end, Let me know if I need to set less size of shared buffer as compare to shared-memory then will give a try.

Comment: I don't run my postgresql instances in docker. I clicked on this because it is in the postgresql section. I can't see how you can fit 6GB of shared buffers into the 1GB configured shm_size you have though.

Comment: @RichardHuxton I understand your point, I didn't take a deep understanding about that, but now I have changed the configuration after your suggestion.

Comment: @RichardHuxton my issue is not resolved yet, I tried to increase the shm memory again and it's working somehow.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Can you provide a solution for this issue? because increasing SHM memory is not a good solution in my opinion. I'm also optimizing every queries

Answer (score 1):

I see three options:

1. configure your container so that it allows more shared memory to be used
2. disable parallel query by setting `max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 0`
3. don't run queries that have to exchange that many result rows between parallel processes

Comment: If I will set `max_parallel_workers_per_gather` to zero it may impact the speed of the query and might provide slow performance when let's say 100 users using interface together

Comment: If you set `max_parallel_workers_per_gather` to 0 it will slow down processing if a single user is using the interface. If 1000 users are using the interface, it might save the day, because it prevents the machine's resources from getting exhausted. Try to tune your queries.